# Building and running Spring Boot application in Docker with couple of services using docker-compose?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have simple Spring Boot application which has few other dependencies/services which it uses. It is student-demo project so nothing big, I'm just testing things out and thus I'm new to Docker.

First off, my application uses three different services: `MySQL`, `RabbitMq` (to send some dummy messages to other Spring app), `Liquibase` to initialize tables and insert data.

Application builds fine after `mvn clean` and `mvn install`. But the goal is to start it from cmd using Docker compose. This is my 2nd day with Docker.

Here is how `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/Consumer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar Consumer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8085
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "Consumer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

And here is `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
    #service 1: definition of mysql database
    db:
      image: mysql:latest
      container_name: mysql-db2   
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_USER=root
      ports:
        - 3306:3306
      restart: always
      
    rabbitmq:
      image: rabbitmq:management
      ports:
        - 5672:5672
        - 15672:15672
        
    liquibase:
      build: .
      image: ubuntu-jdk8-liquibase:latest
      depends_on:
        - db
      network_mode: "host"
  
  
    #service 3: definition of your spring-boot app 
    consumerservice:                        #it is just a name, which will be used only in this file.
      image: consumer-image              #name of the image after dockerfile executes
      container_name: consumer-container  #name of the container created from docker image
      build:
        context: .                          #docker file path (. means root directory)
        dockerfile: Dockerfile              #docker file name
      ports:
        - 8085:8085                     #docker containter port with your os port
      restart: always
        
      depends_on:                           #define dependencies of this app
        - db
        - rabbitmq                                #dependency name (which is defined with this name 'db' in this file earlier)
      environment:
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-db:3306/consumer?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
```

After cd into project directory and running `docker-compose ps`:

[image]

My question is, what am I missing, do I need to add some more things to `Dockerfile`? Is the syntax correct in `.yml`? I'm running windows and have Docker Desktop installed.

**UPDATE 1**
After executing command `docker-compose up`, I noticed it started downloading image for liquibase and mysql (it took couple of minutes). After that I got an error.

```
Removing mysql-db2
Recreating f7bf19092bb4_mysql-db2 ...
Recreating f7bf19092bb4_mysql-db2 ... error

    ERROR: for f7bf19092bb4_mysql-db2  Cannot start service db: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
    
    ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
    ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I continued to get same error, even after I set `ports` section to `3306:3307`, and `3307:3307` and setting  `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-db:3307/consumer?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`

Comment: Can you check whether the docker service is up and running?

Comment: I've just update the question

Comment: @Ashok I ran docker-info, but I dont know where to look for if the service is up

Comment: if you can see the output when you run the docker commands then it means the docker service is running

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill all the processes using port `3306`:

```
sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:3306`
```

Then, run your docker containers:

```
`sudo docker-compose up`
```

or else

change `ports: -3306:3306` to `ports: -3307:3306` in your `docker-compose` file and then run the below command again:

```
docker-compose up
```

Comment: I'm on windows,  so sudo wont work...As I wrote in the update I have already try this with ports and had same error. I even did mvn clean, mvn install..but same error again.

Comment: execute this command `netstat -a -b ` and check in the output whether you can see any service running on port `3306`